# Jquery Updated table view after successfull operation

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html-table

I have a table in a page for example:-

```
<tr>
 <th>no</th>
 <th>name</th>
 <th>age</th>
 <th>actions</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>$i</td>
  <td>$name</td>
  <td>$age</td>
  <td><a href="$id" class="delete">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
```

on the click of the delete it will go the controller through jquery and successfully delete the row, after that I want to show the updated table means without that deleted row. for this now I'm using another page and with the table data, on success I'm doing like this:

```
$(.updated_table_view).html(data.view);
```

**is there any other simple way to do this** like without an another page?

Comment: You could probably just do a `closest('tr')` then `fadeOut()`. That would just hide it in the view.

Comment: can you provide a sample code @Rasclatt

Comment: I also want this thing upadate! so @Rasclatt

Comment: You would need to use ajax so you don't have to reload the page. Should probably stick with two pages though, the view and then the page to process the delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably *"...will go the controller through jquery..."* means via Ajax, so if you want it to just do a simple removal, just hide the row:

**jsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/842x2wuc/

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.delete').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var thisBtn =   $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/link/to/delete.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: { id: thisBtn.attr('href') },
            success: function(response) {
                // This will fade out the row
                thisBtn.closest('tr').fadeOut('fast');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```